# Estoy intentando ordenar la inicial del nombre en una columna en otra posicion

Tags: python, pandas

Yo tengo este DF

**Name**

C Roberto

R Carlos

C Ronaldo

y NECESITO

**Name**

Roberto C

Carlos R

Ronaldo C

Pensaba dividir la columna `Nombre` por el espacio que queda entre el apellido y el nombre, y luego volver a unirlos en el orden correcto

```
df[['Nombre', 'Apellido']] = df.Nombre.str.split(' ', expand = True)
```

Gracias

Comment: ¡Estás en [es.so]! Además de traducir tu pregunta, debes mostrar lo que has intentado hasta el momento. Lee [ask].

Comment: Bienvenido. Te quedó algo de inglés y no se entiende la pregunta. Para preguntas en inglés ve a [so]

Comment: **Necesito**. Por favor muestra lo que has intentado. Puedes leer [mcve]. Para poder ayudarte debes mostrar que lo has intentado. Saludos

Comment: Pensaba dividir la columna Nombre, por el espacio que queda entre el apellido y el nombre, y luego volver a unirlos en el orden correcto


df[['Nombre', 'Apellido']] = df.Nombre.str.split(' ', expand = True)

Comment: @Sports_Science_Help No añadas tu código en los comentarios a tu pregunta. En su lugar edita la pregunta y añade la información que otros usuarios te han dicho que es necesaria.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es necesario que lo separes en dos columnas.
Puedes aplicar la transformación directamente a la columna `Nombre`.

Si quisiera aplicar la transformación a un único nombre lo que haría sería separar la string en dos: la inicial y el apellido.
Para ello usaría el método [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split).
A continuación, construyo una nueva string con el apellido (el segundo elemento resultante del `split`) un espacio y la inicial (el primer elemento resultante de `split`).
Definamos esta operación en una función lambda:

```
swap_nombre = lambda x: f"{x.split(' ')[1]} {x.split(' ')[0]}"
```

Si tu dataframe es algo así:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Nombre': ['C Roberto','R Carlos','C Ronaldo']})
```

Es suficiente aplicarle nuestra función lambda a toda la columna con el método [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html):

```
df['Nombre'] = df['Nombre'].apply(swap_nombre)
```